Indian Passport with Swedish Residence permit - will I need a Visa to visit Scotland?
I checked the website - https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa and when I select Indian passport as my travel document, it notifies I need a Visa.
However, I have a Residence permit issued by Sweden, can I use that to enter the country?
Or is the criteria set based purely on Nationality?

Why do you think that visa information offered by the government of the United Kingdom presents inaccurate advice regarding your need for a visa?

Just want to know if I could use my Swedish Residence permit, or if it has no bearing whatsoever.

@DavidRecallsMonica: not all countries have accurate informations, so not all travellers can asses other countries websites. Indian visa is one of the chaotic one (I hope it improved now, but some website (and eVISa) should not be published until some control of functionality and text).

Will you be actually visiting or do you just need to transit through the UK?

@GiacomoCatenazzi True, but this source is closer to the govt than the usual remote consular office that we sometimes see providing inaccurate info.

When you used the official site you would have been asked for the relevant information. Assuming you answered ‘Indian’, ‘tourism’ and ‘no’ to the question about travelling with or visiting either your partner or a family member in the UK, the answer you got was correct, what made you think it might not be?

@Traveller I was planning to visit a friend of mine, so thought if I could make things easier for me. But based on answer from jcaron, while I will still need a Visa, the Swedish permit might increase my approval rating (At least that is my understanding)

@KarthikNair My point was that if your residence permit had been relevant to facilitating your entry into the UK, the response from the official site would have stated so.

The UK is no longer in the EU, and even when it was, it was not part of the Schengen Area and kept a separate visa regime.
So Schengen Area visas or permits do not automatically give you the right to visit the UK (including Scotland), no more than they allow you to visit the US for instance.
There are a few limited exceptions like transit where they would help, but that probably doesn't apply in your situation.
On the other hand, having a residence permit from Sweden should in general be seen as a strong positive point in a visa application. But you still need to apply (and pay for) a visa, and provide all the relevant documentation.

As a weak passport holder with a German residence permit, I recently had to go this route as well. The visa application was as much paperwork-heavy as for everyone, and it was quite expensive due to fingerprinting costs (in total around 250-300eur incl. fees for passport being shipped back), but I was approved fairly fast (~10 days).
